# ¿Admite María DB Restricciones con nombre usando check?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

He estado documentándome y por más que leo no encuentro solución a mi problema, como ejercicio me han mandado crear una tabla en una base de datos para alojar ciertos datos de un coche, esos datos son:

1. Matrícula
2. Precio
3. Color
4. Cantidad de puertas que tiene el coche

Estoy creando la tabla y quiero alojarle restricciones, vengo de oracle (es más facil ahí y tengo más dominio) pero en este caso debo usar MARIADB (el servicio lo aloja XAMPP) y mi versión es la 10.4.18-MariaDB

Quiero nombrar restricciones de que no sean nulo (no me da problemas) y restricciones de check, quiero que:

1. Obligue la matrícula a cierto formato usando expresiones regulares (1234CDE)
2. El precio del coche sea mayor a 0
3. La cantidad de puertas esté entre 2 y 12

Este es el código:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Base de datos: `concesionarios_programacion`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `coches`
--

CREATE TABLE `coches` (
  `matriculaCoche` varchar(8),
  `precioCoche` double,
  `colorCoche` varchar(10),
  `cantPuertas` int(1)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--  
--  Modificación de la tabla `coches`
--  

ALTER TABLE `coches`
  ADD CONSTRAINT PK_COCHE PRIMARY KEY (`matriculaCoche`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT COCHE_NONULO (`matriculaCoche`) NOT NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT PRECIO_NONULO (`precioCoche`) NOT NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT COLOR_NONULO (`colorCoche`) NOT NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT PUERTAS_NONULO (`cantPuertas`) NOT NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT COCHE_MATRICULA_REAL CHECK (`matriculaCoche` REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,4}(?!.*(LL|CH))[BCDFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]{3}'),
  ADD CONSTRAINT PRECIO_MAYORACERO CHECK (`precioCoche` > 0),
  ADD CONSTRAINT PUERTAS
COMMIT;
```

El error me da a partir de crear las restricciones de la matrícula, la parte de comprobación de que cumpla el criterio (0000ABC):
Se encontró una nueva declaración, pero no hay delimitador entre éste y el anterior. (cerca de CHECK)

Al crear el nombre sin restricciones me funciona pero lo que quiero es darle nombre a las restricciones para que cuando estas sean violadas se devuelva el nombre de la restricción y no algo que es muy dificil de identificar.

No se si tiene solución y si me he explicado bien, si me equivoco en algo o faltan datos me comentáis pero es simplemente eso, añadir a esas 3 restricciones un nombre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final no he podido darle nombre a las resticciones, si no le pones el nombre y lo añades en la misma línea de la columna a la hora de crear no da fallos. Si alguien sabe mas lo agradecería